# twitter bootstrap : how to mix classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to properly use Bootstrap.
My LESS file (loaded after bootstrap.css) looks like this :

```
#page {
.container;
}
header {
    ul {
        .inline;
        .unstyled;
    }
}
```

And as a result, I see :

- My #page container has margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto... but no width!
- My <ul> has no inline and no unstyled styles applied!

If I directly change my HTML code as follow :

```
<div id="page" class="container">
    <header>
        <ul class="inline unstyled">
            ...
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
```

...everything works fine.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks for helping,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Bootstrap defines `ul.inline`, so try

```
#page {
    .container;
}
header {
    ul {
        ul.inline;
        ul.unstyled;
    }
}
```

---

`.container` is defined as 2 blocks. Less doesn't combine the style of several blocks as mixin. Don't know a way around this (sorry).

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: What you are suggesting is working well for ul.inline and ul.unstyled, but not for .container because it is declared as .container, without any prefix. So any idea why it is not working for .container?

Comment: @Aurelien Please have a look at the explanation.

Comment: All right, I saw your answer and tried to make sure that less couldnt combine styles of several blocks, but I didn't find any information about it. Anyway, thanks for your help!